# Akka Stream dynamic Sink depending on Message from Kafka topic

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, akka, reactive-streams

I have a Kafka consumer that reads Message. Each Message has an ID and content.

```scala
case class Message(id: String, content: String)
```

Depending on the ID, I want to write the Message into a separate sink. Specifically into a  MongoDB collection. The Mongo provides a Sink that writes it to the DB into the specified collection.

```scala
val sink: Sink[Document, Future[Done]] = MongoSink.insertOne(collection(id))
```

The Problem is, i need to specify the sink when Connecting the Kafka Consumer Source, but each element defines into which sink it should go.
Is there a way to dynamically use a specific sink when an element arrives. Or is this not possible and I should for example, use a different Kafka topic for each id and connect each source to a separate sink?

Comment: For your use case I'll look into using a sink (or writing one) that is able to insert in differenti collections. Unless you absolutely need different sinks?

Comment: you can use Partition: https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/operators/Partition.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not totally clear how the types line up in your example (e.g. the relationship between `Document` and `Message`), but there are a couple of approaches you can take:

- If there are a lot of possible collections and they can't be known in advance, then the least bad option in Akka Streams is going to be along the lines of

```scala
Sink.foreachAsync[Message](parallelism) { msg =>
  val document = documentFromMessage(msg)
  val collection = collection(msg.id)
  Source.single(document).runWith(MongoSink.insertOne(collection))
}
```

Note that this will use a new Mongo sink for every message, which may have efficiency concerns.  Note that if there's a lighter weight way (e.g. in the reactivemongo driver?) which returns a `Future` after inserting a single document, but uses something like a connection pool to reduce overhead for single-document inserts, that will probably be preferable.

- If the collections are known beforehand, you can prebuild sinks for each collection and use `Partition` and the `GraphDSL` to define a sink which incorporates the prebuilt sinks

```scala
// collection0, etc. are predefined and encompass all of the collections which might be returned by collection(id)
val collections: Map[MongoCollection[Document], (Int, Sink[Document, Future[Done]])] = Map(
  collection0 -> (0 -> MongoSink.insertOne(collection0)),
  collection1 -> (1 -> MongoSink.insertOne(collection1)),
  collection2 -> (2 -> MongoSink.insertOne(collection2)),
  collection3 -> (3 -> MongoSink.insertOne(collection3))
)

val combinedSink = Sink.fromGraph(GraphDSL.create() { implicit builder =>
  import GraphDSL.Implicits._

  val partition = builder.add(
    Partition[Message](
      collections.size,
      { msg => collections(collection(msg.id))._1 }
    )
  )

  val toDocument = Flow[Message].map(documentFromMessage)

  collections.foreach {
    case (_, (n, sink)) =>
      partition.out(n) ~> toDocument ~> sink
  }

  SinkShape.of(partition.in)
}
```

Comment: Converting a Message into a Document is absolutely possible. The first approach is exactly what I was looking for.